# R markdown not returning anything from code chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

Revisiting an issue that appears to have been asked before, but the answers aren't quite helping with the issue I'm experiencing.

I have the below in the YAML portion of my R Markdown document:

```
---
title: "Gambling"
output: html_document
date: "2022-12-22"
params:
  data: "spreadspoke_scores"
---
```

I then add the code chunk below to try to display the column names of the dataframe identified above.

````
```{r params$data}
colnames(params$data)
```
````

However, when I knit the file, I get the below result:

```
## NULL
```

I'm not understanding what needs to be done to get the document to pull back results.  I can't find an answer anywhere on here, or on the internet in general, on what I'm missing.

Comment: Unless you override it with your call to `rmarkdown::render`, the value of `params$data` in this case is the literal string `"spreadspoke_scores"`, not a data.frame suggested by the object named by that string. Note that in https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-6.html, the use of `render("5-parameters.Rmd", params = list(data = "aleutians"))` is passing the literal string `"aleutians"` to be used by the rmarkdown code blocks; another good reference for rmarkdown params: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html

Comment: I ran ```render("Gambling.Rmd", params = list(data = "spreadspoke_scores"))``` through the console, keeping ```columns(params$data)``` in the chunk, and got the same results.  I also tried clicking the dropdown on Knit to Knit With Parameters and entered spreadspoke_scores as the dataset, same results.  Is there an easier way to do this than running it through params?  I'm open to anything, I just want this thing to run and am completely solution agnostic.

Comment: Yes. `list(data = "spreadspoke_scores")` is passing a literal string, `colnames("spreadspoke_scores")` will return `NULL`. Perhaps you mean `list(data = spreadspoke_scores)` (without the quotes)?

Comment: I ran ```{r} list(data=spreadspoke_scores)``` and it returned ```object 'spreadspoke_scores' not found```. Is this the intended way to use this? Sorry, I'm trying everything I can to troubleshoot this but I'm failing on each effort.

Comment: You misunderstood. You need to pass the frame itself in `params` when you render it, so you need to call it as `rmarkdown::render("Gambling.Rmd", params = list(data=spreadspoke_scores))`. As I said earlier, `params=list(data="...")` is passing a literal string, it's the same as `params=list(data="hello world I am a string")`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but none of this is making any sense to me. I’m going to try and find some other way to present my findings, I don’t think R Markdown is for me at this point.